# What does the OBD error code P0100 mean?

Tags: electrical, nissan, misfire, maf, obd

**What does the OBD error code P0100 mean?**

I have an engine misfire with the check engine light on in my Nissan N16 Supper Saloon -1300cc - 2000 model year. The engine started to produce less power.
An OBD scan gave the error code **P0100** (referred to MAF sensor error).

**I replaced the sensor, but am still getting the check engine light with engine misfire. What could be the problem?**

**What should I check?**

Comment: Realize a "misfire" code is going to be different than a P0100 code. Did you check the non-MAF replacement problem before just replacing the MAF? The first thing you should have checked was the MAF circuit to ensure there isn't an issue. [OBD-II P0100](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0100) says: "*The MAF may be disconnected, or a wiring connection may be bad*" ... you should really check your wiring.

Comment: p0100= Mass Air Flow Circuit Malfunction, it may not be the MAF itself but the circuit (connector,wiring or ecm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vacuum leaks can cause a bad MAF reading and result in a fault code. I would check The intake boot connected to the MAF sensor for any cracks or holes. I had this code show up on my '94 BMW. I spent the money on a new MAF sensor only to find out that I could have fixed the problem with a $20 intake boot.

Comment: how did you check for leaks in intake boot ???

Comment: it literally had a big hole in it. I didn't see it till I took the MAF sensor off